# How do you pronounce the << operator

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce the [<< operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)?

For example it is used in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream).

Comment: I pronounce it just like it's spelled.

Comment: The link you provided has the pronunciation. `<<` is pronounced "insertion operator". `>>` is pronounced "extraction operator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the context of iostreams, writers often will refer to << and >> as
>   the “put-to” or "stream insertion" and “get-from” or "stream
>   extraction" operators, respectively[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) .

If you are using << for output in C++ programming then I would just call it "put-to".

(Otherwise, that would also be used as the [bitwise left shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_shift#Bit_shifts) in binary operations, but I doubt that is what you meant)

Comment: One cannot use `<<` for output in C programming.  If you mean C++, say it; this C/C++ thing is a myth that does not exist.

Comment: actually I say to and from backwards to that: "cout << x" would be "cout from x" and "cin >> y" would be "cin into y". I agree about insertion and extraction though.

Answer (score 3):

Just found following in [TC++PL 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201700735) page 25, for your reference.

> The << operator (“put to”) is used as an output operator; cout is the
>   standard output stream. The >> operator (“get from”) is used as an input
>   operator; cin is the standard input stream. The type of the righthand operand
>   of >> determines what input is accepted and is the target of the input
>   operation. The \n character at the end of the output string represents a
>   newline.